# Unable to select specific Firebase libraries on Xcode15 using SPM

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, swift-package-manager, xcode15

As described in the title, when using Swift Package Manager to install specific Firebase libraries(e.g; I want only Analytics and Craslytics) on Xcode15.

There are no checkboxes to select multiple libraries on the left side of this pop-up window which used to be there on previous Xcode versions:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue
This is probably Xcode bug
I found temporary solution - delete unneeded libraries in project settings, at "Framework, Libraries, and Embedded Content"

[image]